# Angular 6 firebase deploy can not dist/server

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase

I've been experiencing the following error when I want to deploy my Angular 6 project firebase, please help please

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './dist/server'

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

Comment: what is your project structure?

Comment: I don't fully understand my English is not very good

Comment: I mean how the files are structured in your porject. By Project structure i mean this:    https://itnext.io/choosing-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-in-angular-d987de65ec7#c194

Comment: into an folder named deploy in the angular project

Comment: Can u please tell the whole structure.

Comment: my project is currently being deployed in a way that has been deployed in firebase hosting.
I wanted to add a seo to the project for google searches and then encountered this error when deploying.
the reason for the error server.ts he said.